# Heavy CPU usage only when using Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, pickadate

I discovered the CPU is roaming over 100% when I use Safari to load an web-app that I am building. I realised this when I see a conflict when using `Remodal.JS` ([link](http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/)) and `pickadate.js` ([link](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/)) together and caused a glitch as shown below:

[image: Problem with overlay when using Safari.]

It should instead look like below (rendered correctly in Chrome, Firefox)

[image: Correct rendering using Chrome.]

Note that the modal has width and height of 100%, so it takes up 100% of the window.

The performance in Safari is severely affected. Imagine a modal takes **15 seconds** to load and a pickadate calendar takes **20 seconds** to load... (my computer is Macbook Pro 2.7GHz QuadCore 16GB RAM late 2013 model..)

The CPU is constantly over 100%, as shown below:

[image: CPU usage.]

The problem I had when using the two libraries in conjunction is described in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332851).

However, I would like to know how I can better debug CPU problems, especially browser-specific ones. (i.e. in my case, only Safari causes the problem but not Firefox nor Chrome).

**Temporary Link** - http://new.carshare.hk/car (will delete this link)

Thanks!

Comment: You can try yslow and see if it reports anythings strange --- http://yslow.org/ -- i never used myself and i dont know if safari has tools like chrome to analyze pages but check the dev tools on safari

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serious performance issue when using remodal and pickadate on Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332851/serious-performance-issue-when-using-remodal-and-pickadate-on-safari)