# Serious performance issue when using remodal and pickadate on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, pickadate

I was trying to use remodal together with pickadate so I can create a date-picker and time-picker from within the modal. On first trial I found out the datepicker would be hidden by the remodal, as shown below.

[image: modal]
[image: modal with pickadate, hidden]

To overcome this issue I created a `.full-screen` class for my remodal.

```
.remodal {
    &.full-screen {
        max-width: none;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

It then works perfectly fine in Chrome, as shown:

[image: full-screen modal]
[image: full-screen modal with chrome]

Then I get to test the site on my iOS, and I found out the overlay is messed. I think it got *sticked to the bottom of the active input element*. As shown in both iOS safari and iOS chrome:

[image: pickatime in ios safari]
[image: pickadate in ios chrome]

Normally I would then open my Safari in MacOSX and try to fix the CSS. However, when the same page is being loaded in Safari, there is a strange serious performance hit:

- I couldn't even load the developer tool
- Safari CPU constantly over 100%
- It takes ~15 seconds to load the modal
- It takes ~10 seconds to load the pickadate.

and the result is as below:

[image: safari macosx.]

If you want to try, I have temporarily open the link [here](http://new.carshare.hk/car), click on the green action button and the modal should load. (try it on chrome first, then safari.) and you will notice the difference.

Comment: anyone? see if you can repeat the same error

Comment: Do you think you can either [present an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without concatenated resources and other stuff? It is much easier to debug then. I tried below…

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Safari 6 or some such slightly older version? I don't have that version available at the moment, but I do believe I have found fixes for a few of your troubles.

1. On `.remodal-overlay, .remodal-wrapper` you use
   `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0px)`, remove that.
2. On `body.remodal-is-active .remodal` remove `-webkit-transform: scale(1);`
3. On `.remodal.full-screen` set `height` to `100vh` and `width` to `100vw`
4. On `.remodal` remove `-webkit-transform: scale(0.95);`, also remove `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;`

By now your positioning should be better. But some performance issues still linger.

Your CSS and JS files are concatenated making it a bit hard to properly walk through what is happening, but I do notice a few things you might want to look into:

- Rather than creating two time selectors and two date selectors you might want to only create one of each and attach it to the input element which is currently focused. This should remove some strain on the browser. [There is support for this](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/).
- Have you tried including `legacy.js` for `pickadate.js`?
- Even on a 2013 Mac with Safari 8 it is sometimes choppy. Do you maybe have other date- and time pickers to try?

Comment: Hi Niklas, thanks for your answer. Do you know why Safari is so different form Chrome in this sense? and do u need a unminified version of javascript to further see the problem?

Comment: It's very hard to track down problems with the web site like that. If you can create a [reduced](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) case (in other words remove as much as possible from the HTML+CSS+JS while still experiencing the slowdown) that would be awesome. Also, which versions of Safari and Chrome are you using?